# Changing one date format to another

Tags: java, date, format, datetime-format

I 'm getting the date in the following format (`Date` and not `String`):

```
Tue Jun 26 07:00:00 EDT 2012
```

I want to change the format of the date to (Date):

```
6/26/2012 10:19:15 AM
```

so as to update the same in the data base. I tried following code:

```
Date dte;
Date dte1;(Tue Jun 26 07:00:00 EDT 2012)
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("m/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(dte1);
dte  = formatter.parse(formattedDate);
SystemUtils.trace("test", " date>>>" + dte);
```

is yielding the following response:

```
Thu Jan 26 07:00:00 EST 2012
```

Can any one please share the piece of code to do the same asap.

Comment: that is `toString()` method of `Date` implementation. You will have the correct format if you print `formattedDate`. If your column type in database is `varchar` update it with `formattedDate`, if it is a date/timestamp it doesn't matter in which format you store.. after all it is a date.

Comment: [You can NOT create a formatted Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66664791/10819573)

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have to format dates to insert them in a database. If using JDBC, use prepared statements.

To answer your question, though, `m` can't mean *minute* and *month* at the same time. `M` means month. `m` means *minute*.

Answer (score 4):

This code outputs needed for you result:

```
Date dte = new Date();//or something else
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(dte);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this below code will suit your need.

```
public class DateWala {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(new Date()));

   }

 }
```

Comment: Please stop using ` ``backticks`` ` for what is not code. Thanks!

Comment: @Arjan So its only for my backticks that i didnt got any points ??? Donts concentrate on my fingers which are pointing to the moon, but rather admire the beauty of the moon.

Comment: Actually, first I downvoted, then I removed the downvote and fixed the formatting. Please don't waste people's time (I'm not the only one who edited your posts). That said, you posted code without any explanation. I don't upvote that.

Comment: Sorry i didnt knew taking time from the work and helping people by giving a working simple snippet of code is wasting their time...... but thanks

Comment: That's not what I wrote. Anyway, I'm glad you now know how people feel about excessive formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tiny function

```
// send your time
private String convertTime(String dateTime) {
//source format will go there
SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdfSource.parse(dateTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //destination format will go there
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

    return sdfDestination.format(date);
}
```